# Finding and erasing same attributes that "equal" different strings in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have these attributes that are the same but equal different strings.

```
data-g-label="wall fans"
data-g-label="standing house propeller fans"
data-g-label="Superfans"
data-g-label="ceiling house fans"
```

I want to grab all the attributes and strings above.  (data-g-label="wall fans", data-g-label="standing house propeller fans", data-g-label="ceiling house fans", data-g-label="Superfans")

I tried (data-g-label)=("\w+") but VS Code only finds 'data-g-label="Superfans"'. How can I get VS Code to find all attributes listed above? Any suggestions?

Comment: `\w` won't work because it matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and thus anything with an embedded space will not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a character class

```
(data-g-label)=("[^"]+")
```

Comment: Thank you - this works like magic, I love it! - Now I'm just trying to figure out why it works.

Comment: @maxfan if it works you can mark it as solved answer, it uses an [negated or complemented character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges)